# Attempting a TDataset Debugger Visualiser - AV on display

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe

I am attempting to create a simple debug visualiser for TDatasets (well, I'm having to make it a TADODataset for now, so I can use the .SaveToFile method).

I've pretty much copied the TStrings visualiser example suplied by EMBT, but am running into problems when the form is being shown, as it gives me an AV without showing any data.

The top part of the callstack in the AV looks like this:

```
[5003C49E]{rtl150.bpl  } System.@UStrAsg (Line 17745, "System.pas" + 30) + $0
[149038D1]{DatasetVisualiserProject.bpl} Datasetvisualiserframe.TDatasetVisualiserFrame.ThreadNotify + $151
[20A2CA9A]{coreide150.bpl} DebuggerMgr.TDebuggerMgr.OnShowVisualizer (Line 1112, "DebuggerMgr.pas" + 4) + $3B
```

So it's a problem with string assignments, likely unallocated memory? Like the TStrings implementation my ThreadNotify procedure has no code in it.

My 'work' routine replaces the TStrings implementation's AddStringListItems call, and looks like this:

```
procedure TDatasetVisualiserFrame.SetDataset(const Expression, TypeName, EvalResult: string);
var
  TempFilename: string;
begin
  FAvailableState := asAvailable;
  FExpression := Expression;
  IntDataset.Close;

  TempFileName := GetTempFile('DSDebug');
  try
    if FTypeName = TADODataset.Classname then
    begin
      Evaluate(Format('%s.SaveToFile(%s)', [FExpression, TempFileName]));

      IntDataset_ADO.LoadFromFile(TempFileName);
      srcIntDataset.DataSet := IntDataset_ADO;
    end
    else if FTypeName = TKBMMemTable.Classname then
    begin
      Evaluate(Format('%s.SaveToFile(%s)', [FExpression, TempFileName]));
      IntDataset.LoadFromFile(TempFileName);
      srcIntDataset.DataSet := IntDataset;
    end
    else raise Exception.Create('Unhandled class type ' + TypeName);
  finally
    if fileexists(TempFileName) then
    begin
      DeleteFile(TempFileName);
    end;
  end;

  DebugDatasetView.beginupdate;
  try
    DebugDatasetView.ClearItems;
    DebugDatasetView.DataController.CreateAllItems(false);
  finally
    DebugDatasetView.endupdate;
  end;
end;
```

The frame itself has a TADODataset, Datasource and a QuantumGrid component for display (though a DBGrid should work)

Do I need to do something with thread handling because I'm dealing with Datasets or is it something more fundamental?

As a bonus question: My original plan was to take a TDataset and use KBMMemTable's LoadFromDataset routine passing in the original dataset, but soon after starting I discovered I was limited to getting strings back from the debugger so this wasn't possible. Am I mistaken, or is there a tricksy way around it?

Comment: What line does the AV occur on? You can debug the IDE with Delphi itself, by setting Delphi as the host app in the Run menu, Parameters.

Comment: Thanks, that's a technique that I wasn't aware of before. Found one stupid mistake that I hadn't set the procedure to TDatasetVisualizerForm.FrameCreated. Now I'm getting another error about 'Stream object cannot be read because it is empty', but at least I've now got something to go on

Answer (score 2):

After being given the means of how to debug the IDE (thanks @David M) I noticed that I hadn't implemented `FrameCreated` properly.

Other than that, `SaveToFile` also needed the filename with `QuotedStr`, otherwise the file would be created empty and `LoadFromFile` would fail due to an empty stream.

Now it works perfectly :-)